# Settings for individual cells in nicematrix

Tags: nicematrix, cell

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{X[2,l]X[r,m]}[hvlines, cell-space-limits=5pt, width=0.5\textwidth]
text 1 & text 2 text 2 text 2\\ 
\Block[r,t]{}{text 3} & text 4 text 4 text 4\\  
\end{NiceTabular}   

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to set alignment properties for specific cells of `NiceTabular`? In this example, is it possible to place `text 3` to top and right of its cell (now it is right and middle)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, there is no key `h` (*head*) and `f` (*foot*) for the command `\Block` (as there is for the command `\SetCell` of `tabularray`). We only have the keys `t` (*top*) and `b` (*bottom*). The key `t` requires the top line of the content of the block to be used for the alignment with the other cells of the rows (the content is composed in a TeX `\vtop`). For a content of only one row, the key `t` has no special effect.

In your case, it's possible to acheive the desired output, by putting the key `t` for the content of the other cell of the same row...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{X[2,l]X[r,m]}[hvlines, cell-space-limits=5pt, width=0.5\textwidth]
text 1 & text 2 text 2 text 2\\ 
\Block[r]{}{text 3} & \Block[t]{}{text 4 text 4 text 4}\\  
\end{NiceTabular}   

\end{document}
```

Maybe there will be keys `f` and `h` for the command `\Block` in a future version of `nicematrix`...

[image: Output of the above code]